# Problem on formula of pressure

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, pressure

As we know $p=F/A$ where $p$ is pessure, $F$ is force and $A$ is area. 
And we know that p is directly proportional to $F$ . 
Now in case of cutting of vegetable with sharp knife require less force ie less pressure as per formula than cutting of vegetable with blunt knife as it will get cut with more force in this case hence more pressure but this doesn't happen we only see in case of area hence in case of blunt knife less pressure whereas in case of sharp knife more pressure 
Then how can we know when to take force and when area??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F=PA$$

For a given applied force to your knife, and the smaller the area over which the force is applied (i.e., the sharper the blade), the greater the pressure (force per unit area) that is applied to your vegetable. Higher pressure makes the force more "concentrated" making a sharper (smaller area) blade easier to cut the vegetable.

Since the goal is for the knife to penetrate the vegetable with the minimum amount of force, the smaller the applied area (the sharper the knife) the less force is needed to achieve the the same pressure. In other words, the goal is to maximize pressure while minimizing force. That makes reducing the applied area the priority.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is the same thing happen in case of school bags with smaller strip??  Is in that case also the force is minimum ??

Answer (score 0):

Bob D offered a good answer.  Here is a more philosophical one.

You seem to have suggested a false dichotomy: that in any given situation in which pressure is the fundamental quantity of interest, either force is the dynamic variable with area held constant, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

So you have $P = \frac FA$, and you can see from that that $P$ is directly proportional to $F$.

What you aren't accounting for is that equation *also* shows that $P$ is *inversely proportional* to $A$.

You say:

> Now in case of cutting of vegetable with sharp knife require less force **ie less pressure as per formula** than cutting of vegetable with blunt knife as it will get cut with **more force in this case hence more pressure**

This completely neglects the inversely proportional relationship between pressure and area; which when taken into account actually implies that it requires the *same* pressure for a sharp and blunt knife.

This fits what we expect from [strength of materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_of_materials); where the primary factor in determining failure of a material is the local [stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(mechanics)) which is measured in units of pressure as well.